# what is the difference between r+ and w+ is modes of file in python?

Tags: python

There are various modes in a file which include read, write,append etc.
r+ and w+ are also among them.
But what is the difference between them?

I was trying to play around with various modes in files in python.
But I couldn't get the difference between r+ and w+.

Comment: The official Python docs explain this, as do many online tutorials.  Here's one that spells out all of the open modes nicely:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-writing-text-files-python/

Answer (score 0):

`r+` does not truncate the file on opening; `w+` does.

And though you didn't ask, but for completeness, `r+` and `a+` both open a file for reading and writing without truncating, but `r+` leaves the file pointer at the beginning of the file, while `a+` leaves the file pointer at the end of the file.

Further, as pointed out by @CryptoFool in a comment, `r+` will not create a file if it does not already exist.

Comment: ...also, 'r+' will fail if the file doesn't already exist where 'w+' will create the file if necessary.